# Versions for css background images when versioning is enabled for css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using "test/test.css?version=1.1" style of versioning to all my css files wherever they are referenced in JS/JSP's. This I am doing to disable cache whenever there is version change.

In my css file, I again have background images for elements. What happens to these images when version is changed for css file? Do I need to add "?version" to these images also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

images won't effect if you change the version number of css file. Because images path will be same even you change the css file version.

Here's how you determine where an image is coming from in Chrome

1. Open your developer tools and go to the "Network" tab.
2. Find "background-image.png" in the list of network requests and click on it's name. and then goto headers tab then you can see `Status Code:200 OK (from memory cache)`

[image]

So images always loads form the cache until its cache of image is cleared.

To update bg images apply same thing like adding version number as query string to background image or try to load bg images by using javascript so that it will be easier to add version number in js.